# 404 error on wordpress expect homepage try all the changes

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

Hi my site is having 404 white screen error expect homepage I try everything from google like to add .htaccess file. When ever I set my permalink to /?p=121 it show the page but when I turn it to something else 404 cameback.
using this code for .htaccess.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What other links are you trying? Can you access the admin? If so, go to the Settings > Permalinks section, and hit save. This often fixes 404 errors.

Comment: error is gone by something else , it was a server side error server was not pointing the .htaccess fiile

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the permalink settings on WP Admin to Post Name

also check the permission on .htaccess if its 660

you can check it here if you need [reference](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-posts-returning-404-error/)

Comment: also where it is located in?

Comment: the file permission of .htaccess so that it will be readable and writable

Comment: "i already try post name not working ? what is 660?" did you change first to any of the suggested on wordpress ? then save then post_name ?